# IntelliJ IDEA file timeout?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to work/debug on scripts in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5

I'm working off files that are stored on a remote VM, but every time I drag+drop my scripts into the edit window it appears for a few seconds and then closes again.

This doesn't happen when I take the files and copy them locally, which is why I'm assuming that this is an issue with a timeout, due to issues with my connection to the VM, but it's 100 times more practical to work on them right from the VM.

Strangely enough this doesn't happen all of the time, but when it does it's really irritating.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening in the IDE settings, like removing the refresh of the file, or at least slowing it down?  I'll admit that my knowledge and experience with IDEs is quite limited.

Thanks,

Comment: Why is it more convenient to edit files on a VM?  Could you explain why you aren't running the project on your local box during development?  Do you use version control, and would committing to a repository from local be an acceptable workaround/best-practice?

Comment: They're scripts that are designed to work with a third-party application, and they need to be stored locally on said application (which is on a VM).  I generally do the development locally but for tweaking and debugging it needs to be run in that specific environment, which is a headache to do because i can't load the script from the VM directly.

Comment: Would something like SyncToy or rsync help?

Comment: Should I imagine that since you're saying that, the answer to my original question is: No?

Comment: no you shouldn't.  What I am saying is that it's not trivial for me to set up a similar environment to try things out, and it's not something I've ever needed to worry about.  So I am suggesting alternatives, because there are no other replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try changing some of the file synchronization settings.

- To get to the settings, click the wrench icon in the File menu labeled "Settings..."
- Next, in the search box type "file synchronization"
- Click on "General" under the "IDE Settings" separator
- Look at the "Synchronization" section.  Fiddle with those settings.

[image: where to find file sync settings]

Comment: Thank you, that worked! (I'd give you an upvote but apparently I can't even do that yet)

Comment: Instead of an upvote you can accept my answer with the checkbox.  That will probably give you enough reputation to upvote things too.